# How to store a value of AS function in a variable in mySQL?

Tags: mysql, sum

Might be stupid but I have multiplied 2 fields together and created a temporary field using `AS` function. Need to store value of the temporary field to sum it up.

```
select branchNo,prodCode, prodQty, prodPrice, prodQty * prodPrice AS totalProfit
from transaction WHERE branchNo = 14;
```

So I need to sum up totalProfit

Any ideas (I'm new to MySQL)?

Answer (score 1):

If you're just trying to get the total profit across all transactions, you can do this:

```
select SUM(prodQty * prodPrice) AS totalProfit
from transaction WHERE branchNo = 14;
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to just do:

```
select sum(prodQty * prodPrice) AS sumtotalProfit
from transaction 
WHERE branchNo = 14;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT SUM(`prodQty` * `prodPrice`) AS totalProfit FROM `transaction` WHERE `branchNo` = 14;
```

Answer (score 0):

You could just use the sum function together with group by.

Let's say you want to know the sum for every prodCode and for branchNo 14:

```
select `prodCode`, SUM(`prodQty` * `prodPrice`) as `totalProfit` 
from `transaction` 
where `branchNo` = 14 
group by `prodCode`;
```

If you just want the sum use:

```
select SUM(`prodQty` * `prodPrice`) as `totalProfit` 
from `transaction` 
where `branchNo` = 14;
```